# Eclipse egit clone failed: Unexpected end of file

Tags: eclipse, git, bitbucket, egit, bitbucket-server

As I'm trying to clone an existing repository (relatively large, >1Gb) to a new computer, I get the following error message (after approx 45 seconds):

[image]

Despite increasing the remote connection timeout in the git preferences to 10000 seconds, the problem persists.

I am pretty sure that my login credentials are correct since I do get to choose which branch I want to clone.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated (I have been trying for the last 3 hours!).
Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Clone from the command line and open the project afterwards.